# How to count the specific sampling pairs given several samples of a function?

Tags: sampling, sampling-theory

[image]

As illustrated in the figure, we have a function (the solid line) and sample it with a user-defined sampling rate (the blue circles). In addition, we uniformly divide the y-axis into several sub-areas (i.e., $A$ to $F$ in the figure). We define a sample and its adjacent sample as the crossing-sample pair if they belong to the different sub-areas. Examples are illustrated by red squares.

My concern is how to account the crossing-sample pairs given a function and a specific sub-area division.

Comment: For each of the subareas (at a given position $c$ on the $y$-axis), you can find the number of roots of $f(x) - c$. This will correspond to the number of crossing-sample pairs. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes. Directly searching the roots of $f(x)-c$ is a choice. Nevertheless, I am looking for a relationship between the number of crossing-sample pairs and sampling rate (or the frequency of the function). Do you have any ideas concerning on this?